# Tilting a water glass so that you can run faster without spilling water (counter-diabatic driving Hamiltonian)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, hamiltonian, adiabatic

In  [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05687) paper, there is an interesting figure:

[image]

Every attempt I've made to search online to confirm whether or not waiters/waitresses actually do this, has been unsuccessful.

Is there really an advantage to tilt the water as in scenario C of the figure?

Comment: To be clear, your question is basically "do waiters run that fast"?

Comment: No that's not my question. My question is in the last sentence.

Comment: [HOW TO CARRY A TRAY | RESTAURANT TRAINING - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGfb-Vf2HpQ&ab_channel=IntergalacticSupremeGoddessofServiceGinnyMae&t=245)

Answer (score 1):

Sketch C is drawn correctly for a glass of water under horizontal acceleration. As it is accelerating gravity is not the only force acting on it, so it would not remain horizontally level. Tilting the tray would be a way to keep the glass from spilling or sliding on the tray while accelerating. However, I doubt that very many waiters would accelerate quickly with a tray of drinks. If they did they would have to estimate the proper angle changes to match acceleration changes.

Comment: "*doubt that very many waiters would accelerate quickly with a tray of drinks*" — but they would and do.  Remember, changing direction is also acceleration.  Waiters are quite skilled at navigating crowded floors and slaloming around tables.

Comment: "*they would have to estimate the proper angle changes to match acceleration changes*" — yes, but in exactly the same way someone on a bicycle or motorcycle must estimate the proper angle of tilt when they turn a corner.  The first few times, they consciously do the estimation, fail, and fall off.  But after that the calculations become instinctive.

Comment: See: [The Barmaid's Brain: And Other Strange Tales from Science: Ingram, Jay: 9780375402180: Amazon.com: Books](https://www.amazon.com/Barmaids-Brain-Other-Strange-Science/dp/0716741202)

Comment: @RayButterworth I am sure there are some skilled, experienced waiters who can do this,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious though why it was not easy to find anything about this online. Are there any references you can provide for what you're saying?

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm in Waterloo! I live at Fischer-Hallman and Erb.